# Updating a Json file on my machine via a Html page running locally

Tags: javascript, python, html, npm

I wish to organise data in an array called `unknown`, by moving each of its members to either an array called `good` or one called `bad`.

```
let data = {
    "bad":[], 
    "unknown": ["b", "a", "d", "g", "o", "o", "d"], 
    "good": []
};
```

becomes:

```
data = {
    "bad":["b", "a", "d"], 
    "unknown": [], 
    "good": ["g", "o", "o", "d"]
};
```

I have written a little html/javascript tool to help me do this, as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/barra/121v4ow8/193/show/

I actually have the above code running on my local machine and I am accessing it via the File Open dialog in Chrome.

I wish to read/write the `data` object to file on my local computer. So for example, when the html page is loaded I wish to read in the data. Likewise I wish to save the updated data as I so desire. What is the simplest most straight forward way for me to do this? This tool will not be hosted online at any stage, so I will only be using it locally on my machine.

If python or node could be used as part of this simple solution (file server etc.), then I would be also interested in such approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write it from the browser (client code) to a file.

The way that web pages do this is with a server. The server runs some code it could be in JS (node) PHP or ASP and that server code would store it usually in a DB and have two functions one to fetch it and one to store it - we call these endpoints.

Your client would then use AJAX to call the sever and request your [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (your array would be stored in an object) and then write it back, Usually from a submit button.

You would need to tell us if you have a server what language that is in to be able to give you any code.

If you use jquery on your client you can use the ajax get and post methods

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

GET: would be to fetch the data
POST: set (save) the data

Answer (score 0):

No client side language like `js/angularjs` is gonna help you in this case. Instead you can use node to help you achieve this. For example.

- Serve your html file (`index.html` for example) using `node` server like below. (This will be your `app.js` file)

  ```
  var express = require("express");
  var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  var app = express(); 
  var fs = require('fs');
  var fileName = './file.json';
  var file = require(fileName);
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
  }));

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  });
  app.get('/getJsonFile', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(file);
  });

  app.post('/saveToFile', function (req, res) {
   file.object = req.body.data;
      fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(file), function (err) {
       if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
      console.log('writing to ' + fileName);
     });
      });


  app.listen(80, function () {
   console.log("Started on PORT 80");
   });
  ```

Now hitting `localhost:3000` in your browser will render your `html` in browser.

Noe it's time to do the `file` thing with your `json`.

I'm assuming you know how to do `http get/post` requests from your `client`.

Now send post request to a route from client side, something like

```
$.post("/saveToFile", {data: yourJson}, function (data) {
alert(data);
});
```

And to get the file you can simply send a get request from your client to `/getJsonFile`

woof. Hope this helps :)